# How to check if a GPS module is connected to a specific serial port on linux?

Tags: linux, gps

### What I want to do

I need to **test the presence and status of a GPS module** on a specific serial port

> /dev/ttyS2

but I can't find any command that do so.

### Additionnal informations

I'm running on a fedora 15 distro.

I can successfully launch a gps daemon with

> gpsd -G -n /dev/ttyS2

and check the daemon informations with

> cgps

Everything is fine with the values returned (my module is alive and connected). However, this command doesn't allow an external program to easily check if it's working as it should.

---

Any suggestions? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a program (inside the external program) that connects with the specified serial port and baud rate.
Asuming the GPS chip is configured to send in NMEA format via the serial port, 
you will receive NMEA sentences once a second.

Each such NMEA line starts with $GP (for GPS chips).
If you receive that then the chip is working.

To receive more detailed configuration settings, you have to read the manual of the GPS chip manufacturer.

Comment: Yes that did ! Here's the core code : https://gist.github.com/paingineer/5f23b02282553782ceec